# Google AdWords counts only a fraction of the transactions/conversions

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

AdWords seems to be counting only ~5% of the actual conversions?! (purchases)

I know because I have also an Analytics tag which shows the correct number of visits on this page.

Tag-manager snippet is **only** on the thank-you page after purchase.

Here is my thank-you page tag snippet:

**>>> ALL IN THE BODY OF THE HTML <<<**

```
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-103xxMyId"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'AW-103xxMyId');

var transValue = 100;
var transSku = "A-Product";

gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-103xxMyId/TOQHxxSomeIdxxx_oe8D',
      'value': transValue,
      'currency': 'USD',
      'transaction_id': transSku
  });
</script>
```

Any idea why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is your attribution model set as in Google Ads?
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7002714?hl=en

In Google Analytics, the default attribution model is last non direct click. In Google Ads, it's likely that you set it to something different. Fractional conversions is a dead giveaway.